# when to start the kafka broker in a zookeeper ensemble

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

If I have a 3 node ZK ensemble. Do I have to wait for the ZK ensemble to elect a leader before I start any of the kafka brokers? if yes how do I check if the leader is elected?

Thanks

Comment: No, you don't have to wait for Zookeeper to elect a leader. It will be handled in background by the zookeeper nodes and will not affect your operations.

Comment: Thanks that was reassuring, I was thinking the same